# Influence of turning basis coordinate system on rotation of another coordinate system

Tags: matrix, rotation, coordinate-systems

Hy,

I have one base 3D coordinate system. Then i have another coordinate system in this one with position (xyz) and rotation (A,B,C). Now my base coordinate system turn or rotate for example A=30 degree B=95degree and C=179degree. I didnt have problem with calculation of new position of the second coordinate system (x',y',z') but I cant calculate new (A',B',C') according to rotated base coordinate system?

Comment: How is this a question about coding? Please see the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: I need to write a code which could calculate this automaticly.

Comment: In what language? Also, if you have to write it, then show us what you've attempted so far. We won't write it for you.